# Показывает Мусор при запуске

Tags: c++

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void main() {
  int n;
  int ** x;
  cin >> n;
  x = new int * [2 * n];

  for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
    x[i] = new int[2 * n];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++) {
      if (i < n && j < n) {
        x[i][j] = 1;
      }
      if (i < n && j > n) {
        x[i][j] = 2;
      }
      if (i > n && j < n) {
        x[i][j] = 3;
      }
      if (i > n && j > n) {
        x[i][j] = 4;
      }
    }
  for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++) {
      cout << x[i][j];
    }
  }

  _getch();
}
```

Comment: А что должно показывать?

Comment: У Вас не учтены варианты, где i=n для любого j и j=n, для любого i. Вот во всех комбинациях этих индексов и получаете мусор.

Answer (score 0):

Ваши условия не покрывают случай, когда `i` или `j` равно `n`, а стало быть в ячейках с этими индексами остаются неинициализированные данные. Просто добавьте предварительно обнуление в цикл установки значений:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2 * n; j++) {
      x[i][j] = 0; // <-- вот это
      if (i < n && j < n) {
```

Ну или обрабатывайте ветку отдельно.